# Pass Activity to service

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

Need to pass Activity to Service. I am using

`intent.putExtra("messagedialog",  this.messageDialog)`

to pass the activity.

However when i try to get the activity using

```
messageDialog = intent.getParcelableExtra("messagedialog");
```

it returns `null`.

Is there i am missing something.

Comment: In what cases do you need to do something like that?

Comment: I need to show activity from which end developer can override. like he can overide color/font/layout

Comment: You mean you want a third-party service to modify your activity at runtime??

Answer (score 4):

> Need to pass Activity to Service

Whatever problem you think you are going to solve this way, there is a better solution. You may wish to post a question on [an Android developer support site](http://www.andglobe.com), where you explain in detail how this service and this activity are supposed to interact.

> Is there i am missing something

First, an `Activity` is not `Parcelable`.

Second, even if you attempt to implement `Parcelable` on `Activity`, passing data via `Intent` extras is not pass-by-reference, but rather pass-by-value. Your service would retrieve a useless, detached copy of the activity, not the actual activity that (perhaps) is running.

> I need to show activity from which end developer can override. like he can overide color/font/layout

Have the client send your service a `PendingIntent`, such as via an `Intent` extra. Your service can then `send()` that `PendingIntent` when needed. The `PendingIntent` can point to an activity that the client chooses to be shown.